# Consulta en MySQL buscando texto específico en una columna con otra columna con datos repetidos

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Tengo la siguiente tabla (es una única tabla):

```
CREATE TABLE `padron` (
  `dni` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nombrecompleto` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `domicilio` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dni`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;

INSERT INTO `padron` VALUES (12345678, 'Pablo Lopez', 'San Martin 1524');
INSERT INTO `padron` VALUES (21345789, 'Pedro Lopez', 'San Martin 1524');
INSERT INTO `padron` VALUES (3245789, 'Jorge Montaldo', 'San Martin 1111');
```

Y necesito encontrar el DNI y nombrecompleto de dos personas (supongamos "pedro" y "pablo") pero que vivan en un mismo domicilio.

Armé la siguiente query sobre esa tabla, pero no responde a lo que necesito

```sql
SELECT dni, nombrecompleto, domicilio
FROM
padron
WHERE
nombrecompleto LIKE '%pablo%' OR
nombrecompleto LIKE '%pedro%'
GROUP BY
domicilio
```

Sólo me devuelve el resultado de Pablo Lopez, pero no también el de Pedro Lopez.
Mi idea es que me devuelva los 2 resultados.
No he encontrado forma de hacerlo, soy bastante novato en SQL, muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuantas tablas tienes, domicilio y dirección son lo mismo?, seria bueno que pusieras un ejemplo real

Comment: Muestra la estructura de tus tablas y muestra el resultado que obtienes al realizarvdicha consulta

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from padron where domicilio in (select domicilio from padron group by domicilio having count(*) > 1);

+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| dni      | nombrecompleto | domicilio       |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
| 12345678 | Pablo Lopez    | San Martin 1524 |
| 21345789 | Pedro Lopez    | San Martin 1524 |
+----------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Es lo que quiere, no?

Comment: Estoy cerca con eso, pero en realidad la query debería ser más específica que eso. ya que quiero encontrar sólo a pablo y a pedro, no a todos los que tienen el mismo domicilio..... en alguna parte debería agregar la condición: **WHERE nombrecompleto LIKE '%pedro%' OR nombercompleto LIKE '%pablo%'**. Pero no sé donde.

Comment: Despues de "....count(*) > 1)" y antes de "order by..."

Answer (score 0):

completando la respuesta anterior, creo que solo faltaria seleccionar las direcciones de pablo y pedro en el group by:

```sql
select
    *
from
    padron
where domicilio in (
    select
        domicilio
    from
        padron
    where
        nombre LIKE '%pablo%' OR
        nombre LIKE '%pedro%'
    group by domicilio
    having count(*) > 1)
order by domicilio;
```

Comment: Gracias por responder. Creería que funciona, pero estoy haciendo una consulta en una tabla con 1 millon de registros, lleva mas de 5 minutos y todavía no responde la query. ¿habrá forma de optimizarla con un join?

Comment: los cambios no son muchos:
select t1.* from padron t1
inner join (select domicilio from padron where nombre LIKE '%pablo%' OR       nombre LIKE '%pedro%' group by domicilio having count(*) > 1)) t2
on t1.domicilio = t2.domicilio order by domicilio;